# Finding second minimum value in raster tiff file

Tags: r, raster, tiff

How can I find the second minimum value in a raster? I have a raster and I would like to compute the range of values. The minimum value is coming 0, so I would like to the second minimum value.

```
Example data
set.seed(42)
require(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
```

Comment: This raster object has no data in it

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to sort the values and then take which ever index you like. For example

```
sort(values(r1))[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot load all values into RAM (as required for MrFlick's solution) this might work:

```
keep <- c(Inf, Inf)
f <- function(x) {
   sort(c(keep, na.omit(x)))[1:2]
}

library(terra)
r <- rast()
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
g <- global(r, f)
g
#      global_1 global_2
#lyr.1        1        2
```

And then use the second value